# Spark: write a CSV with null values as empty columns

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using PySpark to write a dataframe to a CSV file like this:

```
df.write.csv(PATH, nullValue='')
```

There is a column in that dataframe of type string. Some of the values are null. These null values display like this:

```
...,"",...
```

I would like them to be display like this instead:

```
...,,...
```

Is this possible with an option in `csv.write`()?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a need to set `nullValue`? If you remove the option, does it default to write nothing at all?

Comment: It does the same thing with and without `nullValue`. Setting `nullValue=''` was my first attempt to fix the problem, which didn't work.

Comment: You can try to do `df.fillna('').write.csv(PATH)` instead. Basically force all the null columns to be an empty string.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, empty strings are also written as "" in the output CSV.

Comment: Interesting. If your dataframe is not too large, you might want to consider converting it to a Pandas dataframe then do the write. That might work.

Comment: Is it `String` `null` or `null` `object`.  Can you give sample record and code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Easily with `emptyValue` option setted

`emptyValue`: sets the string representation of an empty value. If None is set, it use the default value, `""`.

```py
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.shell import spark

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(col_1=None, col_2='20151231', col_3='Hello'),
    Row(col_1=2, col_2='20160101', col_3=None),
    Row(col_1=3, col_2=None, col_3='World')
])

df.write.csv(PATH, header=True, emptyValue='')
```

Output

```
col_1,col_2,col_3
,20151231,Hello
2,20160101,
3,,World
```

Comment: It's strange. When I use `df.write.format('csv').option('nullValue', None).save(PATH)`, it writes empty value. But when I use it like `df.write.csv(PATH, nullValue=None)`, it writes emtpy **string** value - double quotes

Comment: I see the same behavior you indicate with setting `nullValue`, but setting `emptyValue` as the answer suggests seems to produce the desired output.